# Convert Submitted CiviCrm Membership Form to PDF

Tags: wordpress, forms, pdf

Please does anyone know how to generate a pdf document from Membership Forms submitted by members n Civicrm? Is there a way to implement this.

I am using Civicrm/Wordpress

Comment: Can you indicate how the form is implemented (is it WordPress to CiviCRM API or a CiviCRM profile?)

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM sends a email with PDF attached to it. It has all the data that a membership form has. This email is send to member but you can add CC or BCC in contribution page settings under Thanking-you and receipting.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear from your question what should be in pdf and when it should be generated. It would help if you provide more context to the question.

But I might have a suggestion the CiviRules extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) and the PDF Api extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/pdf-creation-api) could do the job. With CiviRules you could setup a rule which if fired when a membership is added (or updated) to the system and the action could be create PDF. The create PDF action is in the pdf api extension.

Documentation of CiviRules could be found at: https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest